# How to Install Linux OS on USB Drive and Run it On Any PC

Tags: linux, software-installation, usb-drive

I would like to full install Linux on USB and use it in any computer. I tried to install it from a live USB installation using gparted first to clear the partittions. After that I created an ext4 partittion setting the mount point to root ("/") during the installation. But, it complains about a lack of an EFI partition (which I created in one of the attempts). Besides this the installation halts with an error and the process doens't finishes. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
I did all of this following instructions found within google which does not talk about EFI partition.

Comment: Do you want to boot the installed system both in BIOS mode and UEFI mode or only one of the boot modes?

Comment: @sudodus In both. But at least BIOS.

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175899/boot-ubuntu-18-04-from-external-hard-drive-on-a-computer-with-windows-10/1176233#1176233) and links from it may help you.

Comment: "Any computer" is quite a wide target, even if you restrict to a single architecture (x86_32?).  It seems that you'll also need to handle traditional and UEFI BIOS implementations, and possibly even hardware that requires a signed bootloader.